# Checking condition for each row in dataframe based on values of several following rows - very slow code

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

In a dataframe `df` containing the columns `person_id` (int), `dates` (datetimes), and `is_hosp` (boolean), I need to find out for each date of each person_id if is_hosp is true in the next 15 days following the date of the row.

**EDIT:**

Following pertinent comments to the orginal question, I should specify that the dates of observations for each row / person_id are not always consecutive (ie a person_id can have an observation on the 01/01/2018 followed by the next observation on the 08/01/2018).

I have written the code below but it is very slow.

To replicate the issue, here is a fake dataframe of the same format as the dataframe I am working on:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

count_unique_person = 10
dates = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1))
dates = dates.to_pydatetime().tolist()
person_id = [i for i in range(1, count_unique_person + 1) for _ in range(len(dates))]
dates = dates * count_unique_person
sample_arr = [True, False]
col_to_check = np.random.choice(sample_arr, size = len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['person_id'] = person_id
df['dates'] = dates
df['is_hosp'] = col_to_check
```

Here is how I have implemented the check (column `is_inh_15d`), but it takes too long to run (my original dataframe contains a million rows):

```
is_inh = []
is_inh_idx = []
for each_p in np.unique(df['person_id'].values):
    t_df = df[df['person_id'] == each_p].copy()
    for index, e_row in t_df.iterrows():
        s_dt = e_row['dates']
        e_dt = s_dt + dt.timedelta(days = 15)
        t_df2 = t_df[(t_df['dates'] >= s_dt) & (t_df['dates'] <= e_dt)]
        is_inh.append(np.any(t_df2['is_hosp'] == True))
        is_inh_idx.append(index)
h_15d_df = pd.DataFrame()
h_15d_df['is_inh_15d'] = is_inh
h_15d_df['is_inh_idx'] = is_inh_idx
h_15d_df.set_index('is_inh_idx', inplace = True)
df = df.join(h_15d_df)
```

I don't see how to vectorize the logic of checking each of the next 15 days for each row to see if "is_hosp" is True.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Your example has consecutive dates, so you could use a standard window function. Look into `DataFrame.rolling()`

Comment: Does your dataframe contain all dates? With this I mean: is 15 days = 15 rows. Then you can use `.rolling()` or a construction with a temporary DataFrame where you add 15 `.shift(-i)` columns

Comment: thank you, good point. Unfortunately the real dataframe does not contain consecutive dates. Any suggestion to avoid loops/improve the speed? thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rolling()` accepts `"16D"` for 16 days on time series data or datetime-like index.
(16 days means the day of a row and its next 15 days)

```py
is_inh_15d = (
    df.sort_values('dates', ascending=False)
    .groupby('person_id')
    .rolling('16D', on='dates')
    .is_hosp.max() == 1
)
df2 = df.join(is_inh_15d, on=['person_id', 'dates'], rsuffix='_15d')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful. 15 days seem to get the results I expect.

Comment: @cl_frp: I think this one is better than my answer.

Comment: @ndclt you're correct; I think I quite like all the explanation in your answer but using .rolling does make it simpler. Will change the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think I find something. I modify the data generation at the beginning in order to have much more False. `sample_arr = [True, False]` is changed to `sample_arr = [True] + [False] * 10`. With the previous line, it's really hard to get 15 days False.

The solution I found is:

```py
to_concat = []
for i in range(15):
    to_concat.append(
        df.groupby('person_id')
        # the resample get the 15 days following and I use the offset to move 
        # forward
        .resample('15D', offset=pd.to_timedelta(i, 'D'), on='dates')
        # max function give if there is a True (consider as 1)
        .max()
        # there is some date outside initial date range due to the offset I
        # removed with the following line
        .drop(['dates', 'person_id'], axis='columns')[
            lambda x: (x.index.get_level_values('dates') >= df['dates'].min())
            & (x.index.get_level_values('dates') <= df['dates'].max())
        ]
    )
# I reset index in order to have them as column 
# which more looks like your initial dataframe
df = pd.concat(to_concat).sort_index().reset_index()
```

I try to compare both method by doing an `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal` on both result dataframe and I get 2% of difference on the value for the `is_inh_15d` column. I don't know exactly where it comes from.

The solution seems to be around 8 times faster from a `time` command on Linux:

```
python ./op_solution.py  6,90s user 0,79s system 113% cpu 6,797 total
```

```
python ./other_solution.py  0,86s user 0,76s system 231% cpu 0,699 total
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Very useful tricks in there to improve dataset operations performance in general: I'll reuse those often.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the method by sorting by person and date and then using the number of days gaps between appointments per person to generate h_15d_df column. It's kind of hard check because of the dataset but I reduced the days from 15 down to 1 to check and it seems to work.

```
start = time.time()
ori_func()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
16.748218297958374

start = time.time()
new_func()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

0.15230989456176758
```

It's a little bit convoluted but I measured ~x100 times improvement

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import time

def create_df():
    count_unique_person = 10
    dates = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1))
    dates = dates.to_pydatetime().tolist()
    person_id = [i for i in range(1, count_unique_person + 1) for _ in range(len(dates))]
    dates = dates * count_unique_person
    sample_arr = [True, False]
    col_to_check = np.random.choice(sample_arr, size = len(dates))
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['person_id'] = person_id
    df['dates'] = dates
    df['is_hosp'] = col_to_check
    return(df)


def ori_func():
    df = create_df()
    is_inh = []
    is_inh_idx = []
    for each_p in np.unique(df['person_id'].values):
        t_df = df[df['person_id'] == each_p].copy()
        for index, e_row in t_df.iterrows():
            s_dt = e_row['dates']
            e_dt = s_dt + dt.timedelta(days = 15)
            t_df2 = t_df[(t_df['dates'] >= s_dt) & (t_df['dates'] <= e_dt)]
            is_inh.append(np.any(t_df2['is_hosp'] == True))
            is_inh_idx.append(index)
    h_15d_df = pd.DataFrame()
    h_15d_df['is_inh_15d'] = is_inh
    h_15d_df['is_inh_idx'] = is_inh_idx
    h_15d_df.set_index('is_inh_idx', inplace = True)
    df = df.join(h_15d_df)
    return(df)


def ExpandGaps(gaps,d,length):
    expand_gaps = []
    for x in gaps:
        if x <= d:
            expand_gaps += [True]*x
        if x > d:
            expand_gaps += [False]*(x-d)
            expand_gaps += [True]*d
    ##Fill in the remainder with false
    expand_gaps += [False]*(length - len(expand_gaps))
    
    return(expand_gaps)



def new_func():
    df = create_df()
    is_inh = []
    is_inh_idx = []
    #Sort by ID and dates.
    df = df.sort_values(by=["person_id","dates"])
    for each_p in np.unique(df['person_id'].values):
        t_df = df[df['person_id'] == each_p].copy()
        #Create list of dates per patient where is_hosp==True
        if t_df.iloc[0]['is_hosp'] == False:
            #true_dates = t_df.iloc[0]['dates'](t_df['dates'][t_df['is_hosp'] == True])
            #Dates where is_hosp is true
            true_dates = t_df['dates'][(t_df['is_hosp'] == True)]
            first_row = pd.Series([t_df['dates'][t_df.index[0]]])
            #Add first row to start if is_hosp == False
            true_dates = pd.concat([first_row,true_dates])
        else:
            true_dates = t_df['dates'][t_df['is_hosp'] == True]
        ##Calculate the gaps between the visits and convert to number of days
        gaps = np.array([(t - s).days for s, t in zip(true_dates, true_dates[1:])])
        expand_gaps = ExpandGaps(gaps,15,len(t_df))
        is_inh += expand_gaps
    h_15d_df = pd.DataFrame()
    h_15d_df['is_inh_15d'] = is_inh
    #h_15d_df['is_inh_idx'] = is_inh_idx
    #h_15d_df.set_index('is_inh_idx', inplace = True)
    df = df.join(h_15d_df)
    return(df)




start = time.time()
ori_func()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

start = time.time()
new_func()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help; other answers ran faster on my end with fewer lines of codes which is why I upvoted/selected them but really appreciate your input too.